# Altium Duplicate Components

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, altium

I am under grad student working with Altium Designer and recently I found a very peculiar problem If any one can help me I shall be thankful

[image: In PCB editor I found two duplicated Components which is not present in Schematics]

[image: Only Place I found a possible error is this schematics]

As you can see there are two extra copies of SoC which came in editor

Only place I could find annotation problem

I have tried force annotation and other method but couldn't resolve the error

Comment: Are you using a Parent and Child sheet hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, I am doing the same

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be specific without seeing the whole schematic, but it looks to me like you have a component U2 which is made of multiple parts that may or may not be within the same heirachy.

The 'B' denotes this this is part of the component. You might have Part 'A' as power, Part 'B' as the IO, Part 'C' as Serial data etc...

In your PCB editor, the underscore with number (U2_1 and U2_2) denotes which child sheet this component is from.

Perhaps consider moving all parts of component U2 to a schematic sheet which is higher in hierarchy (more towards the parent level)